# MySQL Reflexive/recursive relation

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, relation

I am having a problem trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE autor 
(
id_autor VARCHAR (2),
nom_autor VARCHAR (30),
rfc_autor VARCHAR (15),
pseudo_id VARCHAR (2), 
PRIMARY KEY (id_autor),
FOREIGN KEY (pseudo_id) REFERENCES autor(id_autor)
);
```

When I try to run the following script:

```
INSERT INTO `revistas`.`autor` (`id_autor`, `nom_autor`, `rfc_autor`,`pseudo_id`) VALUES ('A3', 'Quijote','','A7');
```

MySQL shows:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`revistas`.`autor`, CONSTRAINT `autor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pseudo_id`) REFERENCES `autor` (`id_autor`))
```

Any idea why?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe it should be:

```
FOREIGN KEY (pseudo_id) REFERENCES autor(id_autor)
```

Comment: Do you have a `autor` record with and `id_autor` value of `A7`?  A record must be present in `autor` before you can assign it to another record in the `pseudo_id` field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Linger. It was my fault indeed. I had to create that record first!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the reference back to the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE autor (
    id_autor VARCHAR (2),
    nom_autor VARCHAR (30),
    rfc_autor VARCHAR (15),
    pseudo_id VARCHAR (2), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id_autor),
    FOREIGN KEY (pseudo_id) REFERENCES autor(id_autor)
---------------------------------------------^
);
```

This works on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca7f60).